# Formula for time in Excel

Tags: excel

I am looking for a little help with excel. I need a formula for time.

If AK has time then stop, if not look at AC if AC has time then Stop if AC is blank then look at U, if you have time then stop, if you don't have a time then look at M.

I have an excel sheet that I am working on..

Starting with column AK I need a formula that will look at AK to see if there is a time in it. ( I would leave blank or enter a time) if I have entered a time then that’s it. If there is no time there then I need the formula to look at column AC. If i have entered a time there then the formula needs to stop. If that is blank then I need it to look at column U. Same thing If blank then move to the last column M.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58698813/edit) to clarify it. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be useful in doing so

Comment: What do you mean by "having time"?

Comment: You most certainly need VBA and not a formula.